Twilio: How can I separate the user input audio and the generated audio sent via bidirectional stream?
We are developing an application which will transcribe audio from inbound calls to our Twilio number using the Gather verb, doing some processing, then streaming back audio using the Connect Stream verb to trigger a bidirectional stream.
This works, but now we would like to develop an interrupt feature, in which user input during the audio playback portion of the stream will be continuously transcribed, and will interrupt the audio playback stream if there is a meaningful transcription. The Gather verb will not work here as it is not known a priori when to trigger the Gather verb.
Initially, I tried to achieve this functionality by using the inbound track of the bidirectional stream. However, the inbound track actually mixes the user input and the audio that is being fed to the stream from our backend. So, there is no way to continuously transcribe user input using just the inbound track.
I have tried to work around this by:

Setting up a separate unidirectional stream, to see if the inbound and outbound tracks would separate the user input and generated audio chunks.
Setting up a conference in which one call captures the user input and the other call plays back the generated audio, then streaming the audio of the input call using a unidirectional stream.

Neither of these approaches have seemed promising. Is there something I am missing in the approaches I have tried so far? Is there something else I should try? Or is this feature generally not supported in Twilio? In short, what can I do to isolate the user input in an inbound Twilio call?
Thank you for your help!
